# Expected value of a X~Geometric(p) given X < k.

Tags: probability

I know the intuition behind the opposite case (e.g. X > k). But I cannot seem to understand this intuitively.

Is there an elegant answer? I try to brute force this calculation, but my answer looks ugly.

Comment: ${\sum_{x = 1}^{k-1} x \cdot P(X=x)} \over {P(X<k)}$

Comment: Yeah, that is the equation I am trying to simplify.

Comment: Denominator is a G.P. which is fairly easy to calculate. Numerator is a A.G.P. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence
which is not difficult either.